# How to join two csv with same number of rows

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have two CSV files which are sorted and having the same number of rows. I want to join these two CSV files.

```
1.csv
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

2.csv
10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18

result.csv
1,2,3,10,11,12
4,5,6,13,14,15
7,8,9,16,17,18
```

I tried with
 `cat 1.csv 2.csv >result.csv`
 but it appends instead of joining.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Job for `paste`:

```
paste -d, {1,2}.txt
```

`-d,` sets the delimiter as `,`. `{1,2}.txt` is brace expansion, done by shell, would be expanded to `1.txt 2.txt`.

---

If you fancy a bit of `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' OFS=, {1,2}.txt
```

- `NR==FNR` will be true only for the first file; `{a[FNR]=$0; next}` creates an array `a` with record numbers as keys, and records as the values
- For the second file, `{print a[FNR], $0}` prints the array element at the corresponding line number followed by current record; `OFS=,` sets the output field separator as `,`

**Example:**

```
$ cat 1.txt 
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9

$ cat 2.txt 
10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18

$ paste -d, {1,2}.txt
1,2,3,10,11,12
4,5,6,13,14,15
7,8,9,16,17,18

$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} {print a[FNR], $0}' OFS=, {1,2}.txt
1,2,3,10,11,12
4,5,6,13,14,15
7,8,9,16,17,18
```

Comment: will this works when the csv 1.txt have fields with a newline inside?